# How can you make better tasting water with Silver Pulver and Mocca Master?

Tags: boiling, water

I want to make great water. My process

- Filter water first through Brita
- Put silver pulver to paper filter in Mocca Master.
- Experience the taste and adjust the amount of silver pulver.

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26270858_Bacterial_treatment_effectiveness_of_point-of-use_ceramic_water_filters) one publication in African setting, but it is about bacteria. I am interested in using Silver to make better taste in water because of positive feedback from my friends about the topic.

---

How can you make water taste better with Silver Pulver in Mocca Master?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about cooking, but water purification.

Comment: It is about making good water, not just water purification. The problem is that you cannot purify too much, and I would like to understand how you can make good water from dirty tap water.

Comment: I understand what you are asking for @Masi, I'm just saying this isn't the right forum to ask it.

Comment: @GdD I made it now clearer. I am interested in making good taste of water, not about purification itself. I would like to use silver there because of good experiences from my colleaques.

Comment: @GdD Why would it be off topic? It is the preparation of a beverage for consumption, so cooking. (OK, in English "cooking" does not strictly cover beverages, but we have always had them in scope).

Comment: Yes, and good water, you need in every quality food. I want great water.

Comment: "good water" is different than "taste good" and "taste good" is subjective.

Comment: What is silver pulver?

Comment: @Paparazzi Some pulver form containing some amount of silver.

Comment: So does silver pulver taste good?   Do you add it to other foods?

Answer (score 1):

If you want water that was as pure as possible, and your contamination consists of solids or dissolved salts, you need to distill it - if that yields great taste is another matter, and using distilled water as a drink is the topic of a health controversy (would be safe for cooking in any case).

If the contamination is of dissolved gasses or hydrocarbons (organic solvents, volatile odors) activated charcoal might be your best bet (but neither charcoal nor distillation will guarantee that an UNSAFE contamination with such is dealt with!).

Silver tends to produce very unpleasant smelling compounds when corroding, so it might not really help....

Comment: What are those compounds? Can you be please more specific? They are probably only with too high concentrations of silver.

Comment: SIlver sulfide. The black stuff in tarnish. If actually disturbed, smells like burnt rubber and foul eggs. Luckily not very soluble in water.

Comment: How do you get silver sulfide? Is it with high temperature? Then, probably coffee machine is not the optimal with silver. What do you think about silver with cold water? Can you point to any source about the unpleasant smelling compounds when filtering. I have never done it so I do not know.